# php code to test pdo is available?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) but I'm not sure whether my hosting has set it up properly.

How can I test, in PHP, whether it is setup and working for MySQL?

Comment: Should PDO not be available, you could fall back on xpdo.org (emulates API).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113262/how-to-determine-if-pdo-enabled-in-php/6113496#6113496

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Aside from using phpinfo() to see if it's correctly listed

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
```

Answer (score 40):

PDO is always installed for php 5.1+. You can check for specific db drivers that are installed or not using phpinfo(); You could try to check for specific drivers using @Mark Baker idea and checking for specific constants;

```
var_dump(defined(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE)); // mysql
var_dump(PDO::FB_ATTR_TIME_FORMAT)); // firebird
```

Note that not all drivers have specific constants defined so phpinfo() remains best solution.

Using command line you can check using:

```
$ php -m
```

As an alternative of phpinfo() you can use:

```
extension_loaded ('PDO' ); // returns boolean
// or
extension_loaded('pdo_mysql');
// or get all extensions and search for a specific one
get_loaded_extensions();
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

should give applications supported by PHP

```
Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite )
```

Comment: This is a better answer, will list all available not just one.

Answer (score 8):

Using command line, for PDO:

```
php -m|grep -i pdo
```

For PDO with MySQL support:

```
php -m|grep -i pdo_mysql
```

To install php mysql support, search for the package name (Ubuntu):

```
apt-cache search php5*|grep mysql
```

And install it if not already did (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: It should be noted that these commands only work on *nix systems (this may not be immediately obvious to someone new to web server administration). there are some alternatives for the grep command, but sudo and apt-get are different animals. Yes, I know that this is obvious to most, but as I said, not to all.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file that contains

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

It will show you if PDO (and other features are enabled)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows servers, I've found the following useful for checking which PDO extensions are loaded from the command prompt:

`php -m|findstr -i pdo_`

On my system, that command nets me the following results:

`pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite`