# How to determine if PDO is enabled in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a PHP command I can use to determine if PDO is enabled or disabled?

I know I an manually run phpinfo() and eyeball it, but I have a script I run various web servers that display selected PHP configuration settings for the server.

So I am looking to see if there is a command I can use.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

<strike>Check if the class exists:</strike>

```
if (class_exists('PDO'))
```

I appreciate the support and all the upvotes I still get, but please check [Salman Abbas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6113496/511529) for the *proper* way to do this.

Comment: Was going to suggest `defined()` but PDO switched to class constants.

Comment: I tested it and this way works perfectly (both on a server that had it enabled and on a server that did not). Thanks @AJ!

Comment: @AJ: wouldn't it be better to add `false` as 2nd param? If the OP only purely wants to check for existance, but not to autoload the class at the same time, I mean.

Comment: Unless some insane library developer decided to name his *poly-device operator* class `PDO`.

Answer (score 63):

The proper way of determining that will be using the **[extension_loaded](http://php.net/extension_loaded)** function:-

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo') ) {
    .......
}
```

And you might also want to check for the database-specific PDO driver using:-

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo_<database type here>') ) { // e.g., pdo_mysql
    .......
}
```

Comment: Like `pdo_firebird`, `pdo_mysql`, `pdo_oci`, `pdo_odbc`, `pdo_pgsql`, `pdo_sqlite`, `pdo_sqlite_external`

Answer (score 14):

Just run the command as **php -m** from the command prompt which will display list of modules installed for PHP

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

```
if (extension_loaded('pdo')) { /* ... */ }
```

Or (this one is not 100% reliable since it can be implemented in user-land classes):

```
if (class_exists('PDO', false)) { /* ... */ }
```

Personally, I prefer the first option.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
elseif (defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO available';
}
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (in_array('pdo', get_loaded_extensions())) {
   ... pdo is there ...
}
```

Comment: @Dr. DOT: it only *seems*. Plus, AJ didn't write that answer. GolezTrol did.

Comment: I know...not sure how or why I picked up "AJ" -- sorry @GolezTrol

Answer (score 0):

For checking it on **linux terminal** level using above command

> php -m

which would give output related to modules installed from your **php.ini**[image]