# How can I tell if PDO module installed/disabled?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm developing a PHP application.  I just moved a bunch of files over to the production server, to discover that PDO is apparently not installed (`Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in [file] on line [line]`).  The prod server is using PHP 5.3.6; according to the [documentation I've found](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php), "PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0".

I have very little experience administering PHP.  How do I tell if this module is installed but disabled, or absent altogether?  And what do I need to do to get it running?

Comment: Can we see your code in case its just a typo? How are you creating the PDO connection?

Comment: @Ozzy -- It works on my local dev server, so I'm pretty confident it's not a typo.

Comment: You probably need to edit the php.ini file, look for `extension=php_pdo.dll`

Comment: @Ozzy:  The string "pdo" does not occur in the php.ini files on that server (/usr/local/lib/php.ini, /user/lib/php.ini, /etc/php.ini -- I have no idea which one I care about).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if PDO is enabled in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113262/how-to-determine-if-pdo-is-enabled-in-php)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generally you can just do `phpinfo();` to find out what modules are installed.

Or from the commandline:

```
php -m
```

Additionally you could use: [`class_exists('PDO')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) to find out whether the PDO class indeed is accessible.

Comment: php -m does not show PDO, pdo_mysql, or pdo_sqlite, all of which are present in my dev box.  Where should I look to get those running?  Should I assume they're present but disabled, or should I assume I'll have to install them from scratch?

Comment: @BlairHippo What do you use to run your script?

Comment: @BlairHippo It depends. You may be able to activate it in your `php.ini` file. Or you might have to recompile php with pdo and the driver you want to use.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa:  The string "pdo" does not occur in any of the php.ini files on the server (/usr/local/lib/php.ini, /usr/lib/php.ini, /etc/php.ini -- I have no idea which one I care about).  You may be right about needing to recompile PHP.  Unfortunately, the host provider doesn't provide sysadmin support, and nobody in the company is qualified to do it, so I have absolutely no confidence I can recompile PHP without breaking something.  I think I need to curl up under my desk and weep quietly for a while....

Comment: @PLB:  Not sure I understand the question; it's running under Apache.

Comment: @PLB: Fedora 8 (really), Apache 2.0.63.

Comment: @BlairHippo there must be `extension=pdo.so` line in your php.ini

Comment: @PLB:  "cat /etc/php.ini | grep pdo", "cat /usr/lib/php.ini | grep pdo", and "cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini | grep pdo" all return nothing.

Comment: @BlairHippo re-installation is the onliest thing I can advise. It seems that PDO is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal type:

`php -i |grep PDO`

The `-i` is used to display the output of phpinfo().

The `|grep` will filter the list to the ones containing PDO.