# CakePHP Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting

I have shifted my CakePHP (2.3.1 stable version) site to Host-ed.me and I am getting `PDO class not found error`. How to enble PDO on Host-ed.me server. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ask the host to update PHP.

Comment: @john CakePHP 2.3.x does not use namespaces so this is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first compare your previous/local PHP configuration with the configuration on hosted.me.

You can do so by generating a `phpinfo()` report of both. **be sure to remove the phpinfo page afterwards** - having a publicly visible phpinfo page on your website is a major security risk.

Check if PDO is really not installed on the webserver, either via the `phpinfo()` report or via instructions found in this question; [How to determine if PDO is enabled in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113262/how-to-determine-if-pdo-is-enabled-in-php)

You may also check if hosted.me is not using an outdated version of php, otherwise you may run into other problems later on

If PDO is not installed and is required for your website (or the php version is too old), there's no other option than to contact the hosting provider and ask them if it is possible to have it installed or your website be hosted on a different server.

Finally, if these options do not give you a solution, find a better hosting provider that *does* have a decent PHP installation :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog](http://hitechcyberabad.blogspot.in/2013/03/cakephp-resolving-pdo-errors.html) for details.
Basically, you have to do the folllowing:
1. Check if PDO is installed (lookinto your phpinfo() output / write simple program)
2. Install PDO, using yum install php-pdo

Test again, using the above scripts and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the PHP extensions:

> pdo
>
> pdo_sqlite
>
> sqlite

or ask host to enable them