# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the ext

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got my system working on the server on subdomain.domain.com but when i put it on domain.com gives me that error?

Subdomain.domain.com and domain.com are on the same server.

What to do?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception `'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception'` with message `'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded'` in /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:342
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ```
> #0 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(247): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2) 
> #1 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Db.php(270): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) 
> #2 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(142): Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', Array) 
> #3 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(154): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->getDbAdapter() 
> #4 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(683): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->init() 
> #5 /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(629): Zend in /home/take/public_html/google.bg/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 342
> ```

Comment: obviously you need install the PDO extension in your server and/or enable it in your PHP.ini

What OS are you using?

Comment: PDO should be always available for php5.1+. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131411/php-code-to-test-pdo-is-available/3131609#3131609