# Enable PDO using a php script

Tags: php, web-applications, web

I would like to know how can I activate PDO using a php script on the server.

I have done a whole project using PDO, and when moving it to the server, I noticed that PDO is not unable there.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot do this with the php script you must tell that to your hosting provider

Comment: @rsz: It depends on the version -- prior to 5.3 you could use the dl() function to load extensions at run time.

Comment: I have tried                                                         if (!extension_loaded('pdo')) {dl('pdo.so'); }                             and i did got Warning: dl() [function.dl]: Dynamically loaded extensions aren't enabled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131411/php-code-to-test-pdo-is-available

Comment: @ethrbunny I did what's there, and still nothing

Comment: it is surely blocked write an email to hosting provider

Comment: What @rsz said - apparently the provider has disabled it. PDO is supposed to be std for php 5.1 and up...

Comment: Ok will chk with them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if PDO is enabled by your provider by using the **[extension_loaded](http://php.net/extension_loaded)** function:

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo') ) {
    echo "PDO enabled";
} else {
    echo "PDO not enabled";
}
```

You might also want to check for the database-specific PDO driver using:

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo_<database type here>') ) { // e.g., pdo_mysql
    echo "PDO mysql enabled";
} else {
    echo "PDO mysql enabled";
}
```

If it is not enabled, you must contact your provider and ask if it can be enabled.

You might also try to load the PDO extension using PHP's [`dl()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php), but it's unlikely to work if your provider even disabled PDO.