# Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/../../../config/database.php on line 16

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, laravel-5

This is my first project on Laravel 5 and I am trying to up load it to laravel 5. I am trying to add this to a site that is already there. It is going to be inside regular php site. This what I have done so far.

I moved my public folder that was inside my laravel inside of home/public_html/public and renamed it to `public_html/NEW_NAME`. Inside of index I pointed to the new location of app and autoload.

Next home/laravel/NEW_NAME

Inside of the ssh access I ran php composer.phar install to install composer.

Once I do that, i get:

> Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found inconfig/database.php on line 16
>
> Line 16:'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS

I decided to replace: 'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS, with 'fetch' => 8, to see what that would do and I got this

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in /home/dorism120021/laravel/NEW_NAME/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 43
>
> Line 43: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Also, on my godaddy account it says that PDO is select. I am using a sqlite database. PHP 5.5. That is also selected too.

I am not sure what I am missing or what I am doing wrong. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not trust GoDaddy; use `phpinfo()` to double confirm PDO's availability.

Comment: '--enable-opcache' '--with-mssql=shared,/opt/alt/freetds/usr' '--with-interbase=shared,/opt/alt/firebird/usr' '--with-pdo-firebird=shared,/opt/alt/firebird/usr' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/opt/alt/freetds/usr'

Comment: '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared'

Comment: '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/opt/alt/libicu/usr' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/opt/alt/sqlite/usr'

Comment: That is everything I got when i ran phpinfo() Danbopes and Raptor.

Comment: Well, actually you can **edit** your question instead of posting in comments. From the flags you posted, PDO SQLite is installed, but whether it's enabled is still an unknown. Scroll to PDO section to view the status.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve this? it may help me too

Answer (score 0):

PDO Support needs to be compiled in your PHP version in order to use it. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found) for how to correct this issue.

As Raptor pointed out, you can check the availability of this extension by creating a simple php script, and adding `phpinfo();` to it, or by following any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131411/php-code-to-test-pdo-is-available).

Comment: So looked at the two sites you showed me and I ran this line of code. if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO unavailable';
} ------- It came back unavailable