# PDOException could not find driver MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I am trying to make a website that uses PDO to access a MySQL server for registering accounts and logging in etc. However, whenever I try to connect to the MySQL server I get this error:
[Error when a connection attempt is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAhWs.png)

I've allowed friends to attempt to access the database too and they are able to without any difficulties.

Here's what my code looks like:
[Code (Scribbles is my password)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHxv3.png)

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Determine whether you have the mysql driver for pdo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131411/php-code-to-test-pdo-is-available (your exception suggests otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment yet, but this error often occurs when you don't have the pdo_mysql module installed.

Try a phpinfo() in the directory of your site. If you can't find the pdo_mysql module, have a look at the doc to install it:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have included the widening pdo_mysql in file php.ini
If there is not then a line and restart Apache

[ScreanShot php.ini](http://joxi.ru/xAeMRjlIYO1LeA)